# Repeat header when footer by itself

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm looking for some help getting a group header to repeat when the group footer is by itself on the last page.  On my report, this group header is in the 4th group.  The group footer is a grand total that is in the 3rd group.

Sometimes, the records are such that everything in group 4 is on a single page, but the grand total line in group 3 winds up on the next page all by itself.  If that happens, I want to be able to reprint the group header from group 4 prior to this final group 3 footer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you place the header objects in page header?

Comment: I don't think so because not all pages need this header to be on them.